# ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator what does it mean in scala spark?

Tags: apache-spark

When I run my spark program I see this output, and to slow to finished, what does it mean from this context?

```
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 82
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 0
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 69
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 30
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 40
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 61
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 41
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 52
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 29
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 31
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 57
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 60
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 87
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 79
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 78
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 84
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 34
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 49
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 75
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 88
19/04/01 15:34:24 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 48
```

Deps I am using

```
name := "BigData"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.3.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.sqlserver" % "mssql-jdbc" % "6.1.0.jre8"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-xml_2.11" % "0.4.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.19"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.19"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.livy/livy-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.livy" %% "livy-core" % "0.5.0-incubating"

dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.4"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.4"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.9.4"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.liftweb/lift-json
libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.2.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-jackson
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json4s/json4s-native
libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.6.5"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/xdb

//libraryDependencies += "oracle" % "xdb" % "1.0"
```

Comment: What Spark version is you using? This could be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18991

Comment: I am using this version 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below properties to disable ContextCleaner

```
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking false
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking false
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking.shuffle false
spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints false
```

However, if you are running on 2.1 no need to explicitly set these properties

You can get more info from [ContextCleaner](https://mallikarjuna_g.gitbooks.io/spark/content/spark-service-contextcleaner.html)

https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/apache-spark-internals/core/ContextCleaner.html

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer! can you please tell me how I can chage this in a pyspark application? should i change it during runtime, in the spark-submit ? or is there any other option?

Comment: Hello , You can pass with the spark-submit command . Pass above spark properties in --conf section       Command : ./bin/spark-submit --class <main-class> --master <master-url>  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode>  --conf <key>=<value> <application-jar> [application-arguments]    . For  More info refer to below link : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 1):

ContextCleaner runs on the driver. It is created and immediately started when SparkContext starts. Context Cleaner thread that cleans RDD, shuffle, and broadcast states,Accumulators (using keepCleaning method). context-cleaner-periodic-gc to request the JVM garbage collector.The periodic runs are started when ContextCleaner starts and stopped when ContextCleaner stops.